# How can the equation of a hyperbola be $xy=1$?

Tags: conic-sections, quadratic-forms, hyperbolic-geometry

We know that the standard form of a hyperbola is $\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ which is not coherent with $xy=1$. So, how can we say that $xy=1$ is a hyperbola?

Comment: $xy=1$ can be easily rotated to put it into standard form.

Comment: @BrianBorchers So, what is the collective form of all hyperbolas including this one? The more general form.

Comment: In general, you might have an equations of the form $ax^{2}+bxy+cy^{2}+dx+ey+f=0$.  If the discriminant $b^{2}-4ac<0$, then you've got a hyperbola.  Otherwise, you might have another conic section such as an ellipse, parabola, or even a line.

Comment: are discriminant and eccentricity related?

Comment: @BrianBorchers when we put a=0=c=d=e, b=1, and f=-1 then we get a rectangular hyperbola but in that case discriminant is not smaller than zero.

Comment: @BrianBorchers referring to Wikipedia I found out that the discriminant is greater than 0 in Hyperbola. Is that the case Brian?......BTW it is nice to have some answers and interaction with a math professor especially when that I'm a distance learner. thankyou Brian.

Comment: Sorry about the typo in my comment.  Yes, it's "greater" not "less."

Comment: In fact this is a [rectangular hyperbola](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RectangularHyperbola.html).

Comment: Your “standard” form of hyperbola has axes that are vertical and horizontal. No reason why that has to be so in the general case, as both @NickLiu and Arthur have explained in their answers. Here’s another nonstandard hyperbola: $y=x+\frac1x$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually equations in the form of $Ax^2+2Bxy+C^2+Dx+Ey=F$ can be simplified to an equation with variables $u,v$ depends on $x,y$ such that $\{u,v\}$ is an orthogonal basis for $\Bbb R^2$, i.e. one can rotate the graph in $uv$ coordinate into $xy$ plane.

Let $Ax^2+2Bxy+C^2+Dx+Ey=F$.
Then this equation can be written as 
$$q(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix}x&y\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}A&B\\B&C\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}D&E\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}=F$$
Find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $\begin{pmatrix}A&B\\B&C\end{pmatrix}$,namely $v_1,\lambda_1,v_2,\lambda_2$ .
Then a rotation matrix$R$ can be defined as 
$$R=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{v_1}{|v_1|}&\frac{v_2}{|v_2|}\end{pmatrix}\text{ if }\det\begin{pmatrix}\frac{v_1}{|v_1|}&\frac{v_2}{|v_2|}\end{pmatrix}=1$$
$$R=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{v_1}{|v_1|}&-\frac{v_2}{|v_2|}\end{pmatrix}\text{ if }\det\begin{pmatrix}\frac{v_1}{|v_1|}&\frac{v_2}{|v_2|}\end{pmatrix}=-1$$
In such way $\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}=R\begin{pmatrix}u\\v\end{pmatrix}$. One can verify that the $xy$ term in the original given equation would be eliminated. Draw the graph with variables $u,v$ on the $uv$ plane. Then draw $xy$ plane with $u,v$ axis on it, then just draw the graph with respect to $u,v$ axis.

For practice, try graph $x^2+2xy+y^2-3x+y=0$, which is a parabola.

Comment: nice answer Nick although I couldn't comprehend some of the terminology

Comment: I guess the terms you get confused are: (1)orthogonal basis: this means if you draw $u,v$, then $u$ axis is perpendicular to $v$ axis and $u$ intersect with $v$ at the origin, just as $x$ axis perpendicular to $y$ axis. (2) Eigenvalues and eigenvectors: see http://www.sosmath.com/matrix/eigen2/eigen2.html

Answer (score 2):

They are both hyperbolas, but they are rotated $45^\circ$ compared to each other. Specifically, $xy=1$ is congruent to $\frac{x^2}2-\frac{y^2}2=1$.

Answer (score 0):

(Adding to @Arthur)

Consider the rectangular hyperbola $x^2 - y^2 = 2$.

Let's take a point (a, b) of the hyperbola and rotate it by π/4 radian as  follows to get the point (c, d).

[image]

In polar coordinates, $(a, b)= (r\cosθ, r\sinθ)$

$(c, d) = (r \cos(θ+\fracπ4), r \sin(θ + \fracπ4)) = (\frac{a - b}{\sqrt2}, \frac{a + b}{\sqrt2})$

Writing a and b in terms of c and d gives

$(a, b) = (\frac{c + d}{\sqrt2}, \frac{d - c}{\sqrt2})$

Since (a, b) lies on the hyperbola,

$a^2 - b^2 = 2\\
\dfrac{(c + d)^2}2 - \dfrac{(d - c)^2}2 = 2\\
cd = 1$

So the equation of the new hyperbola is:

$xy=1$